# which file need to change for reset password on laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I worked on this file resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php.
but not showing any changes.
Where should I need to do?

Comment: Are you looking to change the form/HTML for the reset password page or something else?

Comment: yes I am talking about html/form changes.

Comment: Perhaps show the code, show what you tried to change, say what you were expecting, say what happened instead, etc. Also, it might help to read [ask]. Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

use this command  in terminal

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: then restatrt you pc maybe your code editors problem